# после завершения анимации появился блок?

Tags: javascript, css

Как сделать так, чтобы только после завершения анимации  (keyframes) одного блока появился второй блок? Можно это сделать только с  помощью css?

Answer (score 5):

Используйте задержку [animation-delay](https://webref.ru/css/animation-delay):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.box-1 {
  background: #03a8f3;
  
  animation: start 1s 0s linear both;
}

.box-2 {
  background: #e81e63;
  
  animation: start 1s 1s linear both;
}

.box-3 {
  background: #4cae50;
  
  animation: start 1s 2s linear both;
}

.box-show {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #fec007;
  
  animation: show 1s 3s linear both;
}


@keyframes start {
  to { transform: translateX(300px); }
}

@keyframes show {
  to { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box box-1"></div>
  <div class="box box-2"></div>
  <div class="box box-3"></div>
  <div class="box box-show"></div>
</div>
```